# Realtek HD Audio is not getting sound to audio jack after windows 8.1 August 12th update

Tags: windows, audio, drivers, updates

I'm working on a toshiba A665-S6050 with Realtek High Definition audio.  I have a High Definition Audio Device Driver From windows and a realtek high definition audio driver.  I installed the R2.75 driver from realteks website but that hasn't helped.  I should also mention Realtek HD Audio shows up in the volume mixer when I plug in speakers or headphones, but it shows it is getting no sound.  My correct default device is selected under sound playback devices and there are no other disabled or disconnected devices except hdmi which i do not use.